# How can I get info from a firebase database with an ID stored in one of the arrays

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am inserting data into Firebase with an unique user ID that's bonded to an account.

I want the user to only be able to see only the data that the user with that ID inserted.

So that when the user inserts into the DB with one phone logged in and goes onto another phone that is also logged in and has the same ID it can only see the array's that has the specific user_id for that account.

What I'm doing right now:

I get the user_id with the Google OAth:

```
package it.bearz.view;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener{
    SignInButton signInButton;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: " + result.isSuccess());
        if(result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.d("Login", "Hello! " + acct.getId());
            getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putString("user_id", acct.getId())
                    .apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, first.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed" + connectionResult);
    }

}
```

Then I insert the data (Uses the user_id but not a real video id yet):

```
SharedPreferences uid = this.getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user_id = uid.getString("user_id", null);

        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference main_db = database.getReference();



        //Use the new reference to add the data
        main_db.push().setValue(new user_object(user_id, "shfgfshgf"));
```

The database looks like this:

[image: DB]

Is there an easy method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the nodes this user created, you can use this `Query`:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(user_id);
```

And then add a Listener to get the video_id.